# is it possible to move/drag the origin of a node link?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

We can move a node links from one socket to another by simply dragging it.

But is there a way to drag the "origin" of a link ?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold CTRL and move with your mouse to move that.

---

just for fun:

you can hold Shift and then drag with the right mouse button over a line, which creates a "reroute" point. This you can move freely with G (or/and mouse)

[image]

you can add as many reroutes as you want.

Comment: That's not what I was searching for, but anyway this is an answer of another question I had :) PS I edited the question.

Comment: i updated my answer