# How do I move a reroute node in the Geometry Node Editor without detaching it from its links?

Tags: node-editor

I can move reroute nodes in the Geometry Editor by holding down the alt key while left-clicking and dragging, but this also detaches them from the links they're is supposed to reroute.

Having to manually plug its links back in every time I move a reroute node seems a bit tedious. Isn't there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out how in an [answer to an unrelated question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/259749/95671):

Select the reroute node, then press the  <kbd>G</kbd> key once to make it follow your mouse cursor. <kbd>Left Click</kbd>  or press  <kbd>Space</kbd> or  <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm, <kbd>Right Click</kbd>  or  <kbd>Escape</kbd> to cancel.

Comment: Of course, just like you can move any other node in both node editors... in the _Geometry Nodes Editor_ as well as _Shader Editor_ and almost everywhere in Blender where you can select things and move them: objects or parts of meshes in the _3D Viewport_, UVs in the _UV Editor_, image strips or sound strips in the _Video Sequence Editor_, keyframes in the _Graph Editor_ etc... So if you ever wonder how to move anything somewhere in Blender: try the G key ;)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know :D I always assumed that everything in Blender can be moved by left-click dragging it or one of its translation handles, it's the first time someone told me the G key is an even more universal way to move things around

Comment: Actually there are a lot of things that cannot simply be dragged around in Blender...